# Modificando una lista en una función

Tags: python, lista

Buen día,

Me he dado cuenta que al intentar modificar una lista adentro de una función únicamente funciona si utilizo `slices` o modifico cada índice de la lista ¿Por qué?

Si se modifica la lista completa adentro de una función de esta forma:

```
def modificaLista(x):
    x = list(set(x))
    print('Adentro de la función:', x)
    return True

nums = [1,1,2,3,4]
modificaLista(nums)
print('Afuera de la función:', nums)
```

Imprime lo siguiente:

```
Adentro de la función: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Afuera de la función: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Pero si asigno la nueva lista al `slice` de toda la lista, es decir `x[:]`, entonces si se modifica:

```
def modificaLista(x):
    x[:] = list(set(x))
    print('Adentro de la función:', x)
    return True

nums = [1,1,2,3,4]
modificaLista(nums)
print('Afuera de la función:', nums)
```

Esto imprime lo siguiente:

```
Adentro de la función: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Afuera de la función: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

De igual forma si intento modificar cada uno de los índices de la lista se puede modificar la lista original:

```
def modificaLista(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        x[i] = x[i] + 5
    print('Adentro de la función:', x)
    return True

nums = [1,1,2,3,4]
modificaLista(nums)
print('Afuera de la función:', nums)
```

Esto imprime:

```
Adentro de la función: [6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Afuera de la función: [6, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Nota:** El código de las funciones no es relevante, son ejemplos para mostrar el "problema".

¿Qué diferencia hay entre utilizar únicamente el nombre de la variable de la lista `x` y utilizar el `slice` de toda la lista `x[:]` o modificar cada índice?

Estuve buscando tal cual en Google pero como no sé el nombre de esta "propiedad" de las listas no he encontrado información útil. ¿Esta "propiedad" tiene nombre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este es un tema *sutil* en python, por lo que vamos a ir paso a paso, primero con algunas cosas básicas del lenguaje:

## Referencias

Primero, debemos comprender que toda variable en python es una *referencia* a un objeto en memoria. Vamos, lo que en otros lenguajes sería *un puntero*, gestionado por python, pero al final, lo que la *variable* contiene es una dirección de memoria, y en esa dirección de memoria reside el *objeto* que está referenciado por la variable.

Cuando tu pasas una *lista* a una función, lo que estás pasando es una *referencia* a esa lista, que existe en memoria.

Por eso, puedes agregar o eliminar elementos de la lista, y estos cambios estarán visibles *fuera* de la función, cuando esta retorne el control. Se puede demostrar con algo tan sencillo como:

```
def modificaLista(x):
    x.Append(10)
    return

nums = [1,2,3,4]
modificaLista(nums)
print(nums)
```

Espero que todo vaya claro hasta aquí.

## Parámetros a funciones

Cuándo tu *pasas* una variable, en la llamada a una función, lo que python hace *tras bambalinas* es una *copia* de dicha variable, que tendrá la referencia al mismo objeto al que *apunta* la variable original. A esto se le llama [pasar por asignación](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference)

Esta distinción es importante, por lo que creo que no estaría mal leer el párrafo anterior varias veces.

En el flujo normal de un programa, generalmente no hace ninguna diferencia el hecho de estar trabajando con una copia de la referencia, pues lo que interesa es el objeto que está referenciado y sobre este operamos.

Pero comienza a ser **muy importante** en el momento que tu asignas una nueva instancia de objeto a esta referencia, que vive solo dentro de la función.

A partir de allí, la referencia que se encuentra afuera de la función seguirá apuntando a su objeto original, y la que está dentro de la función lo hará hacia el objeto que le acabas de asignar.

Puedes comprobarlo fácilmente con esto:

```
def nuevaLista(x):
    x = [4,5,6]
    x.append(10)
    print('dentro', x)
    return

nums = [1,2,3]
nuevaLista(nums)
print(nums)
```

## Tu código

Si revisas tu código, el momento crítico es en el que usas el operador de asignación sobre la referencia

```
x = loQueSea
```

En este momento, esta referencia va a apuntar al objeto que represente *loQueSea* y la referencia externa seguirá apuntando al objeto al que apuntaba durante la llamada a la función.

Para más información, puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/255257) en StackOverflow en inglés.

**Edición**
He editado la respuesta porque creo que la siguiente sección viene bien al caso para entender mejor el código de la pregunta.

## Slice assignment

Cuándo realizas esta operación en el código:

```
x[:] = list(set(x))
```

Lo que está ocurriendo se conoce en python como *slice assignment*, y es una operación que, tras bambalinas, invoca una función que realiza la operación sobre la lista.

En otras palabras, el *slice assignment* es **azúcar sintáctica**, que hace que escribir el código se sienta *bien* y el código se vea espectacular.

Debemos recordar que python [*mapea* funciones a operadores](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) de manera regular.

Es decir, cuándo escribimos:

```
a + b
```

Esto es *traducido* por el interprete a esto:

```
add(a, b)
```

De manera similar, cuándo escribimos:

```
x[i:j] = algo
```

Esto es *traducido* por el interprete a esto:

```
setitem(x, slice(i, j), algo)
```

En concreto, `x[:] = list(set(x))` es traducido a código equivalente a:

```
setitem(x, slice(0, len(x)), list(set(x)))
```

Con todo lo dicho antes, este último fragmento de código deja claro que no está ocurriendo en realidad una asignación a la referencia `x`. La *genial* función `setitem()` se encargará de sustituir los elementos del *slice* por los que se le han pasado.

Esto está documentado en el módulo [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), en la sección [*Mapping Operators to Functions*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) como *Slice Assignment*.

Comment: Entonces, si asigno un nuevo objeto a la variable el apuntador cambia, pero si modifico los valores con los índices o `slices` estoy trabajando sobre la misma referencia de la variable externa. Si utilizo `x=loQueSea` sería como pasar una nueva dirección de memoria al apuntador y si utilizo `x[:]` sería como escribir directamente en esa dirección de memoria. ¿Correcto?

Comment: `x[:]` es un _slice assignment_, que opera sobre la lista a referenciada por x.

Comment: Lo primero que dices es correcto. Lo último, no es _como escribir directamente en esa dirección_, el _slice assignment_ es azúcar sintáctica. Edité la respuesta para agregar una nueva sección que espero aclare el tema.

Answer (score 2):

No sé mucho de Python y de su funcionamiento interno, pero la pregunta me pareció muy interesante así que quisiera aportar mis dos céntimos y que alguien más experto en el tema pueda indicar si estoy en lo cierto o no, pero esto parece ser cosa de la gestión de memoria de Python.
En resumen:

Cuando modificas un único elemento de la lista python te permite trabajar sobre una copia interna (específica para tu método) del objeto. Pero si lo reasignas, python modifica el puntero para que apunte a la nueva lista creada.

Podemos verlo ejecutando el siguiente código:

```py
print('Probamos modificando solo un elemento')
def modificaLista(x):
    x = list(set(x))
    print('Adentro de la función:', x)
    print(id(x))
    return True

nums = [1,1,2,3,4]
modificaLista(nums)
print('Afuera de la función:', nums)
print(id(nums))

print('Ahora probamos modificando la lista entera:')

def modificaLista(x):
    x[:] = list(set(x))
    print('Adentro de la función:', x)
    print(id(x))
    return True

nums2 = [1,1,2,3,4]
modificaLista(nums2)
print('Afuera de la función:', nums2)
print(id(nums2))
```

Con el cual obtenemos la siguiente salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Cuando definimos una lista como:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Tenemos un objeto lista, `[1, 2, 3, 4]` al que referenciamos mediante una etiqueta, `lst`. Por influencia de otros lenguajes seguimos llamando *"variable"* a esta etiqueta, pero no funciona igual.

Si hacemos un cambio:

```py
lst = "Hola"
```

No estamos cambiando el objeto en el que anteriormente había una lista. Lo único de lo que podemos estar seguros es que la misma variable, `lst`, ahora referencia a un objeto string `"Hola"`. No sabemos nada de qué pasó con la lista anterior, aún podría estar "viva" si se sigue referenciando. Cuando no queda ninguna variable que la referencia, un proceso denominado *"recolector de basura"* (GC) se encargará de liberar la memoria que ocupaba.

En las operaciones con listas podemos estudiar varios casos:

```py
lst2 = lst
```

Esta asignación en realidad no crea ningún objeto nuevo, `lst` y `lst2` apuntan a la misma lista. Es algo que se puede comprobar con la función `id()` (`id(lst) == id(lst2)`).

Pero no siempre es así...

```py
lst2 = lst[:]
```

Aquí estamos asignando a `lst2` el resultado de una operación, `lst[:]`. Esta operación es un patrón común en python para hacer una copia de la lista en otra. Ambas listas, `lst` y `lst2`, tendrán los mismo elementos, pero se trata de listas distintas (`id(lst) != id(lst2)`). Lo mismo pasaría con cualquier operación con listas. Por ejemplo, se podría haber clonado la lista de modo más eficiente con `lst2 = lst*1`, pero tenemos asumido como habitual usar el slice, `lst[:]`, cuando se quiere clonar una lista.

Veamos otra operación:

```py
lst[:] = [6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Esta es una operación de *"sustitución"*. Cambiamos un rango de la lista `lst` para incrustar los elementos de otra lista. La variable `lst` sigue apuntando a la lista orignal, pero esta lista *"muta"* en su totalidad para alojar los nuevos elementos.

Si nos centramos en tu pregunta, la diferencia entre:

```py
x = list(set(x))
```

y

```py
x[:] = list(set(x))
```

Está en que la primera, `x` pasa a referenciar una nueva lista, mientras que en la segunda, estamos mutando la lista para incrustarle nuevos elementos.

Mucho ojo con la mutabilidad de listas. Suele ser origen de muchos errores.

Comment: Sobre id(x) == id(y) hace lo mismo que x is y, lo cual dice si ambas variables apuntan a lo mismo. Segundo, copiar una lista NO significa copiar su contenido. Una copia superficial como lista[:] no copia el contenido, solo las referencias.